# What is the fundamental group of a sphere with two points removed?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, spheres

I thought about the fundamental group of a sphere where we remove two arbirary poins. Then I thought thad geometrically one can mabye find a deformation retract to the torus and thus the fundamental group would be $\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z}$ but I‘m not sure uf this is true.

Could maybe someone help me?

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you remove one, you get a (topological) disk. Removing two, you get a punctured disk, which retracts to a circle, eh?

Comment: Sorry I don‘t see why removing two points from a sphere guves s retraction to a circle is there a possibility that you can draw it ?

Comment: Well, the first puncture makes a disk. Then a disk with its center gone can be "thinned" (topologically) to be the thinnest possible annulus, a circle. No? Shrink the outer edge's radius to 1, and increase the inner radius to 1 ... a circle.

Comment: Paul dissected this problem into two steps for you. Which step was unclear? "Both" is a fine answer, but just reiterating that you don't understand is not helpful.

Comment: Aha so when I take away the first point from the sphere to get a disk I need to enlarge the given whole and wrap the surface around?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A different way to see it is that if you take the standard sphere in $\mathbb R^3$ and remove the north and south pole, you can take a projection (that's also a homeomorphism) onto the cylinder $\{(x,y,z) : x^2+y^2=1, |z| \leq 1\}$.

a formula would be to literally send $$(x,y,z) \mapsto \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},z\right).$$

Note that on the North and South Pole, this formula is not well-defined! It's good that we removed it.

Geometrically this is kind of like "widening" a two holes in a sphere until you get to the cylinder.

[This is actually a pretty common homeomorphism!](http://www.matematicasvisuales.com/english/html/geometry/space/sphereCylinderAxial.html#:%7E:text=Each%20point%20on%20the%20sphere,rigorously%20defined%20by%20Johann%20H.&text=By%20cutting%20the%20cylinder%20open,net%20of%20meridians%20and%20parallels.)

Once you have a cylinder, the circle $S^1$ is a deformation retract of your space.

Comment: Very nice argument, +1. One convenient aspect of the usual stereographic projection argument given in José Carlos Santos's answer is that the same argument can be adapted to the case when one removes $n > 1$ points from the sphere. Is there a way to see what's going on in this answer too? It's slightly less clear to me geometrically how to see that this deformation retracts to a wedge of $n-1$ circles.

Comment: @AlexWertheim Truthfully, I think the way that one proceeds will be very similar, since topologically a cylinder is just an annulus, so you would once again resort to having a disk with $(n-1)$ punctures :). I'm not sure about something more clever!

Comment: sorry are $(1,0,0)$ and $(-1,0,0)$ your north and south pole?

Comment: @aprozz yep that’s exactly right

Answer (score 3):

The sphere minus one point is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$. Therefore, the sphere minus two points is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$, whose fundamental group is $(\Bbb Z,+)$.